# Mis-Matched messages from the Message app between two phones?

Tags: iphone, icloud, ios, messages

We have two iPhones running iOS7, and they share an iCloud account, but have separate AppStore accounts.  Both phones are getting messages from the other phone.  Why would this be?  Is it something I can change, or would it be something more along the lines of the something that the phone company can fix?

Answer (score 1):

Under Settings > Messages > Send & Receive

Do you have different accounts or are some of them shared ?